# Generalizing intermediate rules when they will only be used end-to-end on one target

Tags: build, generalization, shake-build-system

I'm writing Shake build rules for some ultimate result `_build/a.4`. Let's say its direct dependency is `_build/a.3`, which in turn depends on `_build/a.2`, and so on to `_build/a.1`. I also have a rule which produces `_build/a.1` in some "bespoke" manner.

Is it better to write these rules as e.g.

```
"_build/a.4" %> \_ -> do
    ...
```

or

```
"_build/*.4" %> \ out -> do
    ...
```

? Note that since the rule for `_build/a.1` is not generalizable, there will never be any other chain than `_build/a.4` and so on, so it is not, in practice, possible to build `_build/b.4`.

On one hand, to me, generalizing the build rules seems like the "nice" way of going around, since it points towards an eventual "librarization" of the build rules. On the other hand, the output of the `--help` flag gives less direction / "false hope" to the user with the generalized version, since it implies that any `_build/foo.4` file that the user can think of will be buildable.